# Why will only this appear but nothing else?

Tags: smoke-simulation, fire

I'm trying to make an animation where a sun spins, then explodes into a supernova and a black hole appears. But I can't seem to get the flares for the sun to stay and when I try to do a test render for the supernova all the light stays in one spot.

Yes, I am using 2 domains for this because I can't use 1 domain for what I need
I baked everything multiple times to make sure everything did what I wanted
I'm using the particle system to get the explosion effect than using the settings for the smoke.
[image: The Render when there should be a supernova (particles)]

[image: The sun model but without any flares]

[image: The shading for the supernova]

[image: The shading for the flares for the sun (just look in the viewport that is what is should look like in the render)]

Comment: To let others to help you solve an issue I would recomend to attach your blend file from previous question. Setup is very complex and there is no chance to solve it from two images. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- **Fluid Cache End** is set only to 50 and for second Domain 500 even animation ends in 1000
- **Source - Particle System** is set, but you didnt specify which one (second field bellow)

Additional issue can come from ...

- you set cache directory same for both domains
  (it means second will overwrite first one bake)
- each flow affects all domains, if you expect one flow affects one domain and another flow affects second domain you have to set them into collections and set specific collection to each domain

Also I see you use Blender 2.82.7, would be more effective to use actual official release 2.83.1 to avoid possible bugs.